# Type casting problem when compiling Confluent KsqlDB

Tags: java, junit, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I am trying to compile (`mvn pacakge` with java 11.0.2) KSQL v5.3.1.

I'm encountering the following error at compiling `ksql-common`:

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.21.0:test (default-test) @ ksql-common ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running io.confluent.ksql.util.WelcomeMsgUtilsTest
...
[INFO] Tests run: 11, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.014 s - in io.confluent.ksql.util.timestamp.StringToTimestampParserTest
[INFO] Running io.confluent.ksql.util.timestamp.TimestampExtractionPolicyFactoryTest
[ERROR] Tests run: 10, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.027 s <<< FAILURE! - in io.confluent.ksql.util.timestamp.TimestampExtractionPolicyFactoryTest
[ERROR] shouldThrowIfTimestampExtractorConfigIsInvalidClass(io.confluent.ksql.util.timestamp.TimestampExtractionPolicyFactoryTest)  Time elapsed: 0.009 s  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: 

Expected: (an instance of io.confluent.ksql.util.KsqlException and exception with message a string containing "cannot be cast to org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.TimestampExtractor")
     but: exception with message a string containing "cannot be cast to org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.TimestampExtractor" message was "Cannot override default timestamp extractor: class io.confluent.ksql.util.timestamp.TimestampExtractionPolicyFactoryTest cannot be cast to class org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.TimestampExtractor (io.confluent.ksql.util.timestamp.TimestampExtractionPolicyFactoryTest and org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.TimestampExtractor are in unnamed module of loader 'app')"
Stacktrace was: io.confluent.ksql.util.KsqlException: Cannot override default timestamp extractor: class io.confluent.ksql.util.timestamp.TimestampExtractionPolicyFactoryTest cannot be cast to class org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.TimestampExtractor (io.confluent.ksql.util.timestamp.TimestampExtractionPolicyFactoryTest and org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.TimestampExtractor are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

Help much appreciated; thanks!

Comment: I'm able to compile v5.3.0 though...

Comment: As @cricket_007 says, you're best off just grabbing the Confluent Platform download. If you really want to get the build working yourself, check out the ksqldb-dev channel on http://cnfl.io/slack or the ksqldb-dev Google Groups https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ksql-dev

Answer (score 0):

You might want to report that issue on Github, but I would like to think the packaging instructions include skipping the tests.

```
mvn package -DskipTests
```

Otherwise, feel free to download Confluent Platform 5.3.1 and only configure and use ksql properties, or use the pre-built Docker images